# Snack Bar with Action Button not aligned to the text

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design

I wonder know why my snackbar is not aligned with the text along with `ActionButton`, it happens **only** when the text is too long. I'm putting a sample image. You know how to do the snackbar stay with your content aligned correctly? If I search ***"Android snackbar"*** on Google Images, I see several examples where it has a two-line text `ActionButton` is properly aligned with the text, and not below, as pictured.

[image: snackbar misaligned]

Comment: This is handled automatically! Your button text is too long and your message is too long to be side-by-side so the API does ^that. What you are looking for will look really odd!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Android resizes the text of description automatically but not the text of ActionButton, so, you need to decrease the text of the ActionButton and put most of the information in the description text.

Then, Android will do the rest.